# Rigid projectile penetrating a solid target at normal incidence

Tags: energy, path-integral, projectile, solid-mechanics

Let's suppose we have an equation that describes the minimum kinetic energy required for a rigid ogival projectile to perforate a target as a function of it's thickness T. Can we use this information to derive a more or less accurate mathematical model that describes the instantaneous resistive force acting upon the projectile along it's path?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; broadly, the derivative of an energy with respect to distance is a force. If you know the incremental kinetic energy required per infinitesimal penetration distance, then this is exactly the force acting on this rigid projectile over that distance:

$$\frac{d[\text{KE}(x)]}{dx}=F(x).$$

Comment: Yes, I've had the same idea, but it's not that simple: what you're suggesting would be true in case the function described the _depth_ penetration into a _semi-infinite_ target. The resistive force would continuously grow with depth, but this is clearly not the case with a finite Thickness as the force must be zero, both at the beginning and the end of the projectile's path.